# How to add the new sheet automatically when the new response of google question come

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Anyone can guide me how to do this. I want to add the new sheet of the google sheet when the response of google question is come one by one. Basically, I do the project which is about create the form. I set the question in the google question and I want to translate the data in the google question to google sheet by drawing the format form. Otherwise, the skill of script editor is unlucky for me.

Comment: Look up onFormSubmit trigger and SpreadSheet.insertSheet().

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be simple starting place. This will append all answers to the chosen sheet.

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()(;
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

Run the following function to create onFormSubmit trigger for the above function.

```
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('formSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

[Form Submit Event Object for spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)